# xorg doesn't start (blackscreen when not root)

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, dwm

I'm running Arch Linux with dwm on my PC and everything was working fine until I played around with my bluetooth settings using `bluetoothctl`. I tried to restart dwm usung `startx` and the screen went black. I found out that, when starting x as a normal user without root permissions, the screen goes black and all I can do is switch to another tty. When I am root however, the screen goes black and after a few seconds, the x server terminates.

Here are my errors and warnings from the root x session:
[image]

Comment: That looks *really* serious. A bunch of directories are missing.